How to solve ERROR w: NG0203 in Angular 18 with Native Federation
I've upgraded my application (host and microfrontends) to Angular v18.2.4 and Native Federation 18.2.2.
The host loads fine, but as it attempts to load another MFE, it seems there is a conflict in Angular versions, and the entire application freezes up.
I used Manfred Steyer's 18.2 update from last month to fix a similar issue when I first tried to handle the upgrade. I thought it was all I needed. It was working for a while. But now it seems again to be due to Angular version mismatch. Did an upgrade to Angular or a library change this?
Or is there something else going on?
I'm using fairly vanilla dependency trees.
This is the host:
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/native-federation": "^18.2.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.4",
    "es-module-shims": "^1.5.12",
    "lazy-line-painter": "1.9.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "umbrella-library": "^2.1.1",
    "windowed-observable": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "js-beautify": "=1.10.2",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }

And this is for the MFEs:
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/native-federation": "^18.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.4",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^16.0.0",
    "es-module-shims": "^1.5.12",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^18.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "umbrella-library": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/build": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "js-beautify": "=1.10.2",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5"
  }

The host loads, but as I attempt to move to an MFE, loading through navigation on the host UI, nothing happens, and this is displayed in the console:
ERROR w: NG0203
    at Kv (https://fleet.dev.com/mf-fleet-reports/_angular_core.x-zcvsTSJQ.js:2:2812)
    at Module.ce (https://fleet.dev.com/mf-fleet-reports/_angular_core.x-zcvsTSJQ.js:2:2939)
    at Gt.ɵfac [as useFactory] (https://fleet.dev.com/mf-fleet-reports/_angular_cdk_a11y.jN-GTyy3AR.js:1:40053)
    at Object.o [as factory] (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:5:12521)
    at uo.hydrate (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:5:11667)
    at uo.get (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:5:10790)
    at zv (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:2:2862)
    at ae (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:2:2939)
    at useValue (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:5:8906)
    at uo.resolveInjectorInitializers (https://fleet.dev.com/_angular_core.HKJhf4bjIv.js:5:11167)


Try to reproduce the error without optimization / minification of code, and you should see a stack trace with unobscured symbol names

There error mostly happens when the core package get duplicated in the bundle. Check the dependency versions.

This happens usually when there is a version mismatch in one of your primary or secondary dependencies.
The versions in the MFE's remoteEntry.json and package-lock.json have to match what the rest of the MFEs and the host are using.
For instance, if you have a dependency for a library that has changed a secondary library dependency, you could get a conflict.
In my case, there were slight version mismatches and I hadn't committed the package-lock.json, so the version reconciliation that the Module Federation algorithm runs wasn't working.
If this is the issue, this should fix it:

Ensure exact matches on shared libraries. For instance, if the host requires angular-core at ^18.4.3, ensure that your MFEs use exactly the same formulation: ^18.4.3.
Run npm install to get a fresh package-lock.json
Commit package-lock.json so it is part of the build process for your MFEs.

Always go inspect the remoteEntry.json and package-lock.json files to check for any mismatches.

is there a way to handle these kind of conflicts with some configuration in federation.config.js?  I mean, it's really difficult deal with this when the microfrontend is shared across several frontends and teams.

I don't know of a way to do it via simple changes in the MFE's federation.config. I agree that would be better, but the plug-in doesn't seem to handle that yet.
